# FTP File upload - script STUCK

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I have a basic bash script that I'm using to copy a file and upload it to my FTP:

```
cp -i /var/mobile/file.db /var
cd /var

HOST=MYFTPHOST
USER=USERNAME
PASS=PASSWORD

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
  user $USER $PASS
  cd websitefolder
  put sms.db
  bye
EOF

rm -f file.db
```

When I run the script, it saves the file to my FTP perfectly. But I'm running the script from different computer's so somehow, I'd like the script to upload the file.db to my FTP like this everytime it uploads it:

- file1.db
- file2.db
- file3.db
- file4.db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but if I understand correctly, you're trying to name the database files in sequential order without overwriting any old files. You'll have to get the list of files from the FTP server in order to find out what files have already been uploaded.

This code will get the list of files from the server that begin with "file" and end with ".db", count them, then change the name of your "file.db" to "fileXX.db", where "XX" is the next number in the naming sequence (i.e. file1.db, file2.db, file3.db, etc).

I'm not sure where "sms.db" came from. I've changed it to "file.db" in the script.

```
cp -i /var/mobile/file.db /var
cd /var

HOST=MYFTPHOST
USER=USERNAME
PASS=PASSWORD

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
cd websitefolder
LIST=$(ls | grep file*.db)
bye
EOF

FILECOUNT=0
for FILE in $LIST
do
    if [ -f $FILE ];
    then
        FILECOUNT+=1
done
FILECOUNT+=1
NEXTDB="file$FILECOUNT.db"
mv file.db $NEXTDB

ftp -inv $HOST << EOF    
put $NEXTDB
bye
EOF
```